# Excel function - SUMIF/S with conditions

Tags: excel, criteria, sumifs

I have a column (A) with a list of numbers (let's say Customer Numbers), and a column B with balances. I need to sum column B with the condition that one particular Customer (let's say 001) is not taken into consideration when summing B column, and also that only negative balances from column B are summed.

I have tried with:
=SUMIFS(B:B;A:A;"<>001";B:B;"<0") but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,"<>001",B:B,"<0")`
I just replaced the ";" with "," in your formula and worked for me.

Comment: For me it theoritically should work with ";". I have created a new small sample table to check and somehow it works, but on the report I am working on it does not. I have no clue why. I have checked cells format. No idea what is wrong with the report :/

Comment: If it still doesn't work - check what formatting you are using in column A on your sheet and let me know. There will be issue with that formula if column A is formatted as TEXT...

Comment: Column A in the report is formatted as General. I have changed it to Numbers, but nothing happened. My sample table is General for both columns.

Comment: Sorry, this is confidential :) Anyway, I found the error. The actual formula was a bit longer than the example I presented and I found a typo error in one of the range criteria - basically I entered A:B instead of A:A in one of the criteria. - thanks for your support and time anyways!